# All Wikipedia pages appear to be highlighted in Google Chrome. How can I fix this?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

This has been annoying me for a while. No matter what I do, Wikipedia pages all look like they're highlighted. I can still highlight text (see the 'Execution' section in the picture), which is really strange. I have already tried the more obvious solutions, like quitting, restarting my computer, and Chrome even updated at one point, but the issue remains.

Thanks for taking a look.

[image]

Edit: My version of Chrome is 18.0.1025.163

Comment: Could you provide more information about your Chrome version. Which Chrome update channel are you on?

Comment: @bioinfoboy I've updated my question to include the version. I think Chrome may have updated when I went to check, since it asked me to restart. When I did, I checked a Wikipedia page, and found that it's exactly as it was when I left it (all highlighted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try zooming in. For some reason, I have the same issue when viewing a Wikipedia article with on OSX - but only if my zoom level is <100%. I think it's related to (or IS) [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113711).

Comment: Hey that did it! Although, I think you meant zoom in.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I did. I'll edit the answer. Glad it worked!