# Why is the background of Wikipedia light blue for me?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All Wikipedia pages appear to be highlighted in Google Chrome. How can I fix this?](https://superuser.com/questions/413265/all-wikipedia-pages-appear-to-be-highlighted-in-google-chrome-how-can-i-fix-thi)

The background of every page on Wikipedia appears light blue to me in Google Chrome:

[image]

Why? I am highlighting no text.

Comment: It's a bug.Try making your zoom 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/130940) that fixes the blue background bug on Google Chrome.

Install it and the blue background bug will be gone.

Hope this helps.